# Template Blogger Blogspot height 100% percent not working

Tags: html, css, templates, height, blogger

My blog has an embed but height=100% is not working

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en" dir="ltr">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title><$BlogPageTitle$></title>
<style>html,body{margin:0;padding:0;background:#000;border:0;height:100%;width:100%}</style>
</head>
<body style="padding:0;margin:0;border:0;height:100%;width:100%">
<Blogger>
<$BlogItemBody$>
</Blogger>
</body>
</html>
```

Demo link: http://embed.vntim.com/2015/01/live.html?sv=http://svtre.com/dogodongky.biz/hitSpoon.mp4&HvieT The frame video player doesn't show (height = 0).

Comment: Your URL looked very much like spam. Please, consider posting [minimal, complete, verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your css applies the height attribute only to the body.  The divs with id "playbox" and "player" still have height 0.

Since it looks like you're embedding a player from another site, do you have a working example of this player?  Maybe start from a working example and insert that into your code.  Generally you don't need to manually style elements of a player like this in order to get it to work.

It could be that there is some sort of deeper problem going on...like nothing showing up inside the box and that's why it's having height 0.

You could try adding CSS to style specific elements by ID, like:

```
#player #playbox{
    height: 100%;
}
```

etc.  but my intuition is that this won't achieve what you want.